# What cmpl $0x1, -0x18(ebp)?

Tags: assembly, x86, att

So I have a line that does logical compare like:
`cmpl $0x1, -0x18(ebp)` . After this it jumps if this is equal, but what exactly does that -0x18(ebp) do?

Comment: (ebp) means the item at the address stored in ebp.  -0x18 is an offset to that so if ebp has 0x1000 then it means take the value read at address 0x1000-0x18

Comment: AT&T has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break it down a bit.

`-0x18(ebp)` takes the value stored in the `ebp` register, subtracts `0x18` from it, and uses the result as a memory address to read from.

Therefore, `cmpl $0x1, -0x18(ebp)` reads the value stored at the memory address calculated from `-0x18(ebp)` and subtracts `$0x1` from it, setting various flags based on that calculation (e.g. setting the zero flag `ZF` to `1` if the subtraction results in `0`). The various `jmp` instructions then determine whether to jump or not based on the flags that were set.